# Filter Traffic On Google Analytics by Different Language

Tags: regex, google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

I have a website that has a structure similar as mentioned below -

"http://www.example.com" [static site], "http://www.example.com/blog" [wordpress]

The above site is in English.

Now, the same website has language versions with a structure similar as mentioned below -

"http://es.example.com" [static site], "http://es.example.com/blog" [wordpress]

"http://fr.example.com" [static site], "http://fr.example.com/blog" [wordpress]

"http://it.example.com" [static site], "http://it.example.com/blog" [wordpress]

The above sites are in Spanish, French & Italian respectively of the same english site.

I have created 4 "Views" [EN+ES+FR+IT] in Google Analytics to track 'static' along with 'wordpress blog' for each language separately. But the issue is, I have no idea what "Filters" to use to track the traffic separately for each language.

Plz help me out to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed. Google Analytics filters looks like solution for your problem. You can use hostname filter like was mentioned in previous comment.

If you need more details how filters are working and how to create filter, please refer to this Google Analytics help: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034823?hl=en&ref_topic=1032939

Answer (score 1):

**Create a hostname filter**, for instance for the `FR` website:

[image]